Процесс не может получить доступ к файлу, так как этот файл занят другим процессом: 'song.mp3'
Описываю проблему, бот воспроизводит музыку, и при нажатии на кнопку, срабатывает команда next, которая пропускает текущую и запускает следующую песню, но, при этом действии мне выдается ошибка, что файл занят другим процессом и я не знаю как это урегулировать. Вот команда на пропуск песни:
async def next(ctx):
    voice = discord.utils.get(bot.voice_clients, guild=server)
    if voice.is_playing():
        voice.stop()
    if len(url_queue) >= 1:
        with youtube_dl.YoutubeDL(ydl_opt) as ydl:
            ydl.download(str(url_queue[0]))
            os.remove('song.mp3')
        for file in os.listdir('./'):
            if file.endswith('.mp3'):
                os.rename(file, 'song.mp3')
    url_queue.pop(0)
    voice.play(discord.FFmpegPCMAudio("song.mp3"), after=my_after)

